# Can a smart pointer passed by reference be a nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

There are many questions about passing smart pointers by reference. What I did not find is a definite answer on: Can we pass a nullptr to a method accepting a smart pointer by reference?

Example:

```
void myFunc(std::shared_ptr<std::string> &myStrRef) {
   // do something
}

void main() {
   myFunc(nullptr);
}
```

Comment: What does your compiler say?

Comment: The fact that `std::shared_ptr<std::string> &myStrRef` is non-const leads me to believe that it's some sort of output parameters. While there are ways to fix the compilation error, whether or not they are correct depends on what the function actually wants to do. It doesn't seem like it was designed to work without begin given an actual `shared_ptr` to set.

Comment: Share_ptr is default itself to nullptr.

Comment: Please don't use `void main()`. The return type of `main` must always be `int` in standard C++. `void main()` is a non-standard compiler extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can we pass a nullptr to a method accepting a smart pointer by reference?

Not with a non-const lvalue reference.

```
void myFunc(std::shared_ptr<std::string> &myStrRef) {
   // do something
}

void main() {
   myFunc(nullptr);
}
```

Will fail to compile because `myStrRef` can't be bound to a temporary object.  If you instead had

```
void myFunc(const std::shared_ptr<std::string> &myStrRef) {
   // do something
}
// or
void myFunc(std::shared_ptr<std::string> &&myStrRef) {
   // do something
}
```

Then it would be legal because those references can bind to a temporary object.

Comment: Note however, that the first case does also not guard against passing an existing (non-temporary) `shared_ptr` that just happens to have a value of `nullptr`.